# What happens to memory allocated by C functions in R language

Tags: r, memory-management, garbage-collection, package

In my R package  , the C code which implements the function allocates some memory for usage.
What happens to this memory ?
Will it be under R's GC's radar or would it be a memory leak ?
If its under R's garbage collection , will this memory be reclaimed back ?

I have a huge 5 GB of data to be allocated in R's server process which is running as a server.
Here it would be a good idea if  i can allocate this memory out of GC's radar like we have outside heap memory allocation in Java.
So basically , can i allocate a huge amount of memory in my C code without R not disturbing that memory ?

I am planning to use malloc or calloc to allocate memory.

Comment: The answer will depend on how you're allocating the memory, which you don't say in your question.

Comment: I would be using the normal methods like malloc or calloc in C to allocate memory.

Comment: No, R does not magically know what memory you have allocated with arbitrary C functions. R does know what memory you have allocated with R's C functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described fairly clearly in "Writing R Extensions" -- one uses R variants of `calloc()` / `malloc()` that access the same pool of memory.  That way R can `gc()` these things, and why you need `PROTECT()` annd `UNPROTECT()`.

> ### 6.1.2 User-controlled memory
>
> The other form of memory allocation is an interface to `malloc`, the
>   interface providing R error handling.  This memory lasts until freed
>   by the user and is additional to the memory allocated for the R
>   workspace.
>
> The interface functions are
>
> ```
>  TYPE* Calloc(size_t N, TYPE)
>  TYPE* Realloc(ANY *P, size_t N, TYPE)
>  void Free(ANY *P)
> ```
>
> providing analogues of `calloc`, `realloc` and `free`.  If there is an
>   error during allocation it is handled by R, so if these routines
>   return the memory has been successfully allocated or freed.  `Free`
>   will set the pointer P to `NULL`.  (Some but not all versions of S do
>   so.)
>
> Users should arrange to `Free` this memory when no longer needed,
>   including on error or user interrupt.  This can often be done most
>   conveniently from an `on.exit` action in the calling R function - see
>   `pwilcox` for an example.
>
> Do not assume that memory allocated by `Calloc`/`Realloc` comes
>   from the same pool as used by `malloc`: in particular do not use
>   `free` or `strdup` with it.
>
> These entry points need to be prefixed by `R_` if
>   `STRICT_R_HEADERS` has been defined.

Comment: Is memory allocated by `malloc` (rather than by `Calloc` and `Realloc`) also handled by the garbage collection?  My assumption is no, and thus the R-specific versions are the proper ones, but I'm clearly casting about in the dark a little bit here.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman: none of those methods are handled by the garbage collector; they're all user-controlled and therefore must be freed manually.

Comment: @dirk - I hope we dont have to use PROTECT/UNPROTECT in congestion with Calloc/Ralloc !!!

Comment: @AriB.Friedman It is not, hence the requirement to switch to `Calloc()`.  It. All. In. The. Manual.

Comment: @VineethMohan I recommend spending some time with Writing R Extension; it beats idle speculation here.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - Thank you for all your time.

Comment: @VineethMohan: It all makes sense once you work through it, and there is not point in us repeating the manual to you here.  What we as users allocatate and 'hand back' to R may (eventually) be freed by R which is why, yes Veronica, we need both Calloc() or PROTECT.  Or just switch to C++ and use our Rcpp package where it all (!!) happens automagically (!!).

Answer (score 0):

From Chambers' *Software for Data Analysis*:

> Whenever any computation could possibly allocate R storage dynamically
>   and the result is not assigned at the R level, the use of the
>   corresponding C reference must be protected by the PROTECT and
>   UNPROTECT macros.  The reason is that the storage would otherwise be
>   released in R happened to do a garbage collection of dynamic storage
>   during the computation.

Comment: I have seen a PROTECT and UNPROTECT function in C code and i feel it has something to do with R's memory management.

Comment: Ari, that is wrong.  You (ie the programmer) does the malloc'ing but you use functions providing by R access its memory pool / allocation.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You're right of course.  I just found the relevant part of SDA and came back to update my answer.  Should be up in a second.