# Dynamic memory allocation in C functions called from R language

Tags: c, r, memory, memory-management

I'm writing an R package that calls a C script. The C script uses a structure with a dynamically determined length: the length of the array `forest->edges` depends on the data passed from R.

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int n_edge;
  ...
  unsigned int max_node;
  unsigned int edges[];
} forest;

forest * forest_new (unsigned int *n_edge) {
  forest *f = malloc(sizeof(forest) + (2 * *n_edge * sizeof(int)));
  f->n_edge     = *n_edge;
  ...
  f->max_node   = 0;
  return f;
}
```

The code runs successfully in C, but crashes when an R call triggers `forest_new`.  My hunch is that the crash results from memory allocation, and indeed the [R manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Transient-storage-allocation) mentions alternative means of allocating memory (e.g. `R_alloc`, `Calloc`), which [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761988/what-happens-to-memory-allocated-by-c-functions-in-r-language/13765249#13765249) [elsewhere](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-March/063565.html) seems to suggest should be used in place of `malloc`/`calloc`.

So part 1 of the question is when calls to `malloc`/`calloc` should, or must, be replaced by R-safe equivalents (perhaps they are irrelevant to my problem?).
Part 2 of the question is how the R-safe functions can handle structures whose length is dynamically determined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `malloc/calloc` and `free` in packages to allocate and free memory, but you have to handle out of memory errors like in any C application. You can use `Calloc/Free/Realloc` provided by R and then you will get the error handled in the "R way" (an R error when out of memory). The `R_alloc` function allows you to allocate temporary data that is freed automatically when your external function exits (when you get back to R, it is stack-based allocation).

R does not care about whether your C code uses structures with dynamically determined length (flexible arrays), R does not access your structure at all.

If you need more help please post a self-contained example or provide more information about the error. Perhaps it is also worth checking `n_edge` has a correct/sane value in `forest_new`.